# Octave pop up message

Tags: octave

I am running Octave 4.4.1 on MacOs Catalina 10.15.7. For some weeks I have been having this message poping up when a code is running: "

> It seems that [name of script] has been modified by another application. DO you want to reload it?

I click Yes each time it pops up, but when the code is running, it just keeps coming back, and sometimes Octave becomes unresponsive although the script has finished running

All I could find on the internet were either some old posts with answers about outdated Octave versions, or very complicated stuff that I would not be able to implement.

Any one knows why this happens, and what to do about it?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is exclusive to the GUI version of Octave, and it comes up if you have a file open for editing in the Octave GUI Editor window, and the file's contents change due to a process unrelated to the Octave Editor.

E.g. you may also be editing the file on an external text editor at the same time? Or your script may be copying / generating a new file under the same name as a file that you've got open in the editor, effectively overwriting the now-out-of-date version that's still being displayed in the Octave Editor?

Octave gives you this warning to prevent you from 'saving' in your editor, and therefore undoing any changes that had been made by the external process in the meantime.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have a big for loop in my script that import data from a webpage. At each loop, it fills more columns. Would that be it? the imported data (actually, none of the variable) is displayed in the GUI though...

Comment: @Lucile do you have a file open in the editor?

Comment: I open a file in my script yes (xlsread).... then I modify it in the script, and save it again. Is that the problem? if yes, then it means I should only open it, then once its content is modified, save it under another name? that's going to be annoying... or could I just open it, then close it, somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure. All I can tell you is that when you have any file open in the OCTAVE EDITOR tab, octave keeps checking if some other process has changed the file, and if so, it gives you this warning message. Obviously if the file is NOT open in the octave editor, you won't get this message. There is also an option in the Preferences that you can tick to stop the warning and update the open file automatically:  Preferences -> Editor -> File Handling -> Reload extermally changed files without prompt

Comment: I did the simple fix with the Preferences settings, it works! cheers for that!